# Can an If Statement tell if an assignment was valid?

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement

I have an object that returns a value if successful and false (or nil) if it failed.

i want to assign that value to a variable

```
if(var1 = [object foo])
{
    //if the [object foo] returned a variable, goes here
}
else
{
    //[object foo] returned FALSE (or nil), go here
}
```

can an If statement detected if an assignment was valid?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by valid? The code you presented will work, though it is usually best to wrap the assignment in `()`, so `if((var1 = [object foo]))`

Comment: anything that is not false or nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question, but let me try and explain a few situations you can check

**1) Property contains value**

```
if ([object foo])
{
    // If foo has a value associated to it that is not nil/false/zero
}
else
{
    // If foo equals nil, false or zero
}
```

**2) Assignment to a variable was successful**

```
if ((bar = [object myMethod]))
{
    // If myMethod returns any non-nil value
}
else
{
    // If myMethod returns nil
}
```

**3) Previous assignment of a variable was successful**

```
bar = [object myMethod];

if (bar)
{
    // If bar has a value associated to it that is not nil/false/zero
}
else
{
    // If bar equals nil, false or zero
}
```

Comment: yep, i new how to two example 1 and 3, i wasn't sure how to do example 2 or if it would work. it seems like a simpler way to do then the other examples to me.

Answer (score 4):

This is all right but will generate a warning, since this is a common typo (`=` instead of `==`). To silence that warning add another set of parentheses like this:

```
if ((var = [object foo])) ...
```

Since this easily can lead to misunderstandings a lot of people will advise against doing this. For a simple `if` statement this is much clearer to do the assignment first:

```
var = [object for];
if (var) ...
```

In `while` loops this is more useful, but also considered harmful by many people.

Answer (score 0):

use `==` instead of `=` in the if statement.

before the if statement, you may have `var1 = [object foo]`
[see comparison operators](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Operators_and_Expressions)

Comment: `=` is correct if he does wish to also assign the value and test the value, but if he wants to compare the two values, then yes `==`.

Comment: His inline comments state: `//if the [object foo] returned a variable, goes here`.  I think the OP is a bit confused and probably does want `=`.

Comment: i did want "=", it is an assignment, not a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by valid that the variable contains an expected result, you can just perform another if on the variable against the expected result, or null to check it.